# persist connection using Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have implemented facebook log in using Facebook javascript SDK in Jquery mobile , now the problem is  i want to persist connection through out all the pages as when ever i refresh the page i need to fire FB.Login again.

Moreover do i need to include following code in every html page to access the FB object ?

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX', // App ID

          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
       }(document));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should include initialization of JavaScript SDK on every page.

JavaScript SDK should set cookie automatically (as you set in `FB.init` call parameters) so you doesn't need to call `FB.login` on every page

Comment: Okay thanks , In care if i replace my custom button with a <div class="fb-login-button"> then determinately i don't have to fire FB.Login , but how would i listen the response once the login is successfull

Comment: `FB.subscribe` to `auth.login` event or use callback for `FB.login` ;)

Answer (score 1):

On each page, you will want to include the Javascript SDK.

On each page in the `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {};`, after calling the normal FB.init() you will want to call FB.getLoginStatus() (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) which will give you the access token for you to use to access the API.

Answer (score 1):

If you call init more than once the SDK responds with 'FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem' in your console log. To avoid that you can test for whether the FB object exists and then load and init the API if it does not.

```
    $( document ).delegate("#my_jqm_page", "pagebeforecreate", function() {

      if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
          console.log("FB JS API is available now");
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // etc.
```